# Variance identities given $E(x)<\infty$

Tags: variance, random-variable, expected-value

ok i got two identities i want to prove (true or false)

1. $Var\left [ \left ( X-E(X) \right )\frac{1}{E(X)}  \right ]=\frac{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}{E(X)^2}$

prove

since $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X) $ , $Var(a+X)=Var(X) $  and $E(X)$ is a finite scalar

$Var\left [ \left ( X-E(X) \right )\frac{1}{E(X)}  \right ]=\frac{VAR(X)}{E(X)^2}=\frac{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}{E(X)^2}$

now, the second one i want to check is

2. $Var\left [ \left ( X-E(X) \right )\frac{1}{X}  \right ]=\frac{E(X)^2}{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}$

.... really don't know how to solve this

Comment: Are you told that $E[X]$ is _finite_ or that $E[X] < \infty$? The latter choice allows for the possibility that $E[X] = -\infty$ for those who allow expected values to be infinite (not all do, these cognoscenti say that while they agree with Charles Dickens that expectations can be great, they must not be infinite).).

Answer (score 1):

The second identity is not correct.

Assuming that $E[1/X]$ exists,
$$\mbox{Var}((X-E(X))/X) = \mbox{Var}(1-E(X)/X)=\mbox{Var}(1)+\mbox{Var}(E(X)/X)).$$

However,

$$\mbox{Var}(E(X)/X))=E(X)^2E(1/X^2)-E(X)^2E(1/X)^2,$$

and generally $E(X)^{-1}\neq E(1/X)$.